# Squash some commits in the pull request but not all of them on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, githooks

Is there a way to merge some of the commits when merging a pull request but not all of them?

I know that one of the merge strategies is to squash all of the commits into one when merging. However, what I am looking for is to be able to squash all commits that have a specific template for the message e.g "update something *" into one commit which is the latest commit.  How can I achieve that?

Is it a server side git hook? or a custom merge strategy? Is that even possible?

Comment: Why not create multiple pull requests? One with the commits that you want to squash (then you select squash all), and others with commits that you dnt want to squash

Comment: Right now I have a git hook "pre-push" that creates a commit with a specific message "update something (git_revision)". so what I am trying to achieve is an automated way (via a hook for example) to avoid having a lot of commits with this message when I merge to develop for example (I want to have only one commit  "update something (git_revision)" per pull-request)

Comment: Create a seperate branch only for "update something" commits. Once you feel you are ready to merge, then do it with squash.

Comment: These "update something" commits are auto-generated by "pre-push" hook so this is not an option

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do pre-push hook on a specific (different, new) branch: [**See more HERE**](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/186)

Comment: I still think creating a new branch is not a good solution, I will have one of these commit every push I do, having another branch means I will double the number of pull requests and merges I have, I feel that this will make the process way more complicated. Thanks for your contribution to the question.

Comment: No it won't be double since the branch will be squashed once every x months, not on each push. Good luck finding a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know bitbucket does not allow that. You can however use

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

to choose among the last 5 commits, wich ones to squash. After that you can merge your pull request in bitbucket just like you would normaly.

Comment: Right now I have a git hook "pre-push" that creates a commit with a specific message "update something (git_revision)". so what I am trying to achieve is an automated way (via a hook for example) to avoid having a lot of commits with this message when I merge to develop for example (I want to have only one commit per pull-request).